# When leaving the page I get: Unhandled GraphQL subscription error Error: GraphQL error: Variable xx of required type xxx was not provided

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I am developing with vue-apollo graphql.

In page multisgs/_id.vue I have a query with several "subscribeToMore" each with a different variable.

```
      variables() {
        return {
          multisigId: this.$route.params.id,
        }
      },
```

When I leave the page I get:

```
Unhandled GraphQL subscription error Error: GraphQL error: Variable "$multisigId" of required type "ID!" was not provided.
```

I have tried:

```
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$apollo.queries.multisig.skip = true
    this.$apollo.queries.multisig.stop()
  },
```

With no luck.

Why am I getting this error when leaving the page?

To give more context, in the layout.vue I am also running a query to all the multisigs in the database:

```
    multisigs: {
  query: gql`query {
    multisigs {
      _id
      name
      address {
        _id
        balance
      }
    },
  }`,
```

So I have to queries with subscriptions to the same entity in different places. When I go to multigs/_id.vue, the query is not executed so I can't see any subscriptions notifications unless I execute:

```
  mounted() {
    this.$apollo.queries.multisig.refetch()
  },
```

I have the feeling that apollo joins both queries into one as they are queries about the same entity multisg. 
This is extremely confusing and annoying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding:

```
  skip () {
    return !this.$route.params || !this.$route.params.id
  },
```

It works even though I don't understand why the query is active when leaving the page.